# Q: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible

Tags: java, appium-android

I have just setup the appium environment and facing the below problem.

> It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible

I have read some solutions but they didn't work.
Please can someone check it and suggest what i might be missing.I need to pass through this.

```
package appiumMobileAPPTestPackage;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class StartApplication {

    private static AndroidDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

        File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "\\Apps\\APKs");
        File app = new File(appDir, "ApiDemos.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 6000); 
        capabilities.setCapability( AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS, true);
        capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.13.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "SM-J700F");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", "5203ac07f4a8939d"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "io.appium.android.apis");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos");
        capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true");

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("https://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

And below exception I am shown. I have changed the mobile device and tried multiple solutions but to no help as of now. Also somebody explain this the exception chain why this has occurred and how did that start.